# Java Beginner - Trying to add some basic graphics, need help. Don't know why this isnt working

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to coding, Java particularly, but I figured I might have known enough now to try to make a very simple 2D game. However, I can't seem to get this code to paint my object, and I'd like some help.. Here's my two classes that are involved:

Main Class (main method):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Window window = new Window(800, 650);
    window.createWindow();

    Game game = new Game();
    game.start();

}
```

And here is the other class with the thread and such:

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;
    int dx = 1;
    int dy = 1;

    public void start() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 500, 500);
    }
}
```

*The main method is all the code I have in my Main Class.

**SOLVED: Here is my Window class, all I did to fix it was simply use the add() method to add the Game Class since it extends from JPanel.

```
public class Window extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int width, height;

    public Window(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    // Frame creation
    public void createWindow(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(width, height);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Test Game");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        Game g = new Game();
        add(g);

    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you define `createWindow`? Also, where do you add your game to the window?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Its in a seperate class, I didn't show it because I didn't want to make the post 99% code

Comment: In general, posting the minimal code is a good idea. In your specific case, you are missing some key details, so I would say that you have not posted minimal code. I can not give you a specific answer without seeing the `Window` class.

Comment: I've partly resolved the issue, so now I understand the importance of the JFrame class, as previously I did not, so I apologize for that. My new issue is that when I change the x value in the thread loop, it doesnt move the object.

Comment: That's a totally different question, so please ask a new question.

Comment: Also, if you do not post more code, I would recommend deleting this question altogether to save me the trouble of trying to get it closed. Without the additional code, it will not be useful to other visitors of the site and is unlikely to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Sure no problem I was just wondering if I could milk this conversation for a little bit more information is all.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Haha sure, Ill add some.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good question, and I'm glad you came up with the solution yourself. I'm still going to provide an answer cause I'm basically getting rep at all costs* at this point. Same reason I want you to ask a new question. Also, it's technically site policy. *I can't use the word I want to use unfortunately.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added the Window class along with an explanation on how I solved the issue  :) I will also start a new question soon, probably.

Comment: Your other problem is probably a concurrency issue. Use the volatile keyword or AtomicInteger.

Comment: I have no clue what any of that is haha, but I'll look it up. thanks.

Comment: I saw your edit, but now the Game you create in the main, is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `JPanel` to a top-level container (Window or Applet) for it to be visible. Creating and adding it in the `JFrame` is one way to do it, but this will prevent the game from being accessible outside your frame without jumping through a bunch of hoops.

A better way might be to add the game in `main`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Window window = new Window(800, 650);
    Game game = new Game();

    window.add(game);
    window.createWindow();
    game.start();
}
```

Notice that `add` is being called before `createWindow`. You generally want to add all your elements to the frame *before* you call `setVisible(True)` on it, since that is what really starts the GUI running.

## Update

To address your comment about painting a thick line instead of a rectangle:

The line happens because you don't clear the previous rectangle. The window is not normally cleared unless you move it or do some other operation outside the program that requires it to be cleared.

One of the things that the default `paintComponent` does is overpaint the whole window with a rectangle of the background color. If you want to make your code more efficient, add you can overpaint just the section that you modified with the previous paint:

```
if(/*On first iteration*/) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
} else {
    g.setColor(getBackground());
    g.fillRect(x-dx, y-dy, 500, 500);
}
g.setColor(Color.cyan);
g.fillRect(x, y, 500, 500);
```

You could potentially optimize even further and only paint the part that you actually exposed from the previous iteration:

```
g.fillRect(x-dx, y-dy, 500, dy);
g.fillRect(x-dx, y, dx, 500-dy);
```

Comment: This fixed my next issue, only now when it repaints, it doesn't clear the screen in between repaints. Basically it draws a line. (I have it so it constantly moves to the right. I know you said to make a new question, but now I consider this as a part of the same issue so I'll keep it in the same forum post.

Comment: Scratch that, figured it out :) Turns out under the paintComponent() method i just had to add the statement: super.paintComponent(g);

Comment: @JustinRobinson. I added an explanation of what is happening there. Please select the answer if it helps you.